# iOS APNs only after authentication sign-in within app?

Tags: ios, authentication, apple-push-notifications, profile

I've looked through Apple's documentation on APNs and I can't seem to figure out if what I'm looking for is possible. I'm trying to create an app that only sends out push notifications after you have signed into the app. I want there to be a public section of the app that anyone can access, but I am hoping to utilize the push notifications to send information I don't necessarily want the public to see.

Can anyone tell me if that's impossible, or if I've missed some documentation somewhere that will get me through what I'm looking for? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Definitely possible!** I actually just recently had to solve this problem :)

---

**Like some of the users mentioned**, one way to do it is just to position when you prompt to allow push notifications. If you wait until a user is logged in to ask you can solve this problem by assuming every user who's said yes has *logged in*.

**See below for some things to think about before choosing this solution!**

---

The hard part is going to be some of the edge cases you may run into. Some things to think about right off the bat might be:

1. **Make sure to think about what happens if a user signs out again after signing in.** Using this solution, that user would continue to receive the push notifications after sign out because they would have already accepted push notifications while they were signed in.
2. **Think about *when* you ask them if they would like to receive push notifications.** Of course, you can ask them only when they've signed in, but you're missing access to all of the signed-out users if you ever want to attempt to get them to sign in and become (i'm assuming) premium users. If you choose to ask them before they've created an account you have the ability to send them messages in the future, even if they are different than the messages you send to your signed in users.

I ran into these issues when we were creating [ToggleHQ](https://togglehq.com) and it was a pain (there are more edge cases too that might take some more time to write up haha).

**We ended up assigning a device to a specific user on login so you can send messages to just those devices (logged in) OR to all devices (consider these the *public* notifications).** You can also send notifications to *logged in users* that have enabled certain types of notifications, but, that's another story.

**One more note:** It's often best to ask users if they want push notifications with a popup that explains a bit more about the benefits *prior* to showing the standard apple popup. That way you can ask them again later if they say no without sending them to the Apple Settings :) What we ended up doing in our own apps (and suggesting others do too) is to find the first point in your app where a user could see the value in push notifications, and ask them then!

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you very much for the info. I might need to pick your brain a little bit more on this when we start development.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible. 
The app will only receive notifications after it requests permissions from the user. Some more [info](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1).

So if you don't want unauthenticated users to get notifications, you can simply have the app ask for notification permissions after the user is authenticated.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Your app can receive push notifications only after user allows push notifications to receive.
To send push notification from your app, you need to call some Web API from your app. 
Hope this helps!

Comment: This does help! Thanks for the feedback.